# Laravel, best place/naming for queries related to multiple db tables

Tags: php, laravel, oop, model, organization

I am working on a Laravel application with many Eloquent Models. These eloquent models (e.g. User, Post, etc) also contain a lot of queries that are only loosely connected to the model (often raw sql).

Some queries are like, 'get me some information from one table, some of another and a little of info from a third table'. Now models like the User model can have a lot of methods like `getAllUncompletedActionsForUser` or `getSessionsDurationsPerUser`. I think it is not nice if an eloquent model will have a thousands lines of code.

What would be your take on splitting these models, where would you put and how would you name classes that return database results that deal with many different tables?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the bottleneck of the [active record](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) pattern. This is why so many people refer to it as anti-pattern.

Instead of trying to squeeze more functionality in the same class, you should start moving the *only-vaguely-related* persistence logic to standalone [data mappers](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html).

Kinda like this:

```
$user = App\Entity\User::find($id);

$mapper = new App\Mapper\UserActions($dbConnection);
$mapper->fetchIncompleted($users);

var_dump($user->getActions(App\Entity\User::ACTION_INCOMPLTE));
```

Of course you will probably want to use IoC (if possible) for injecting these mappers in the given service, instead of having to use `new` operator in some random location.

Comment: I will look into it, seen this pattern before but think it may be messy if don't use mappers all the time. Also I though the mapper is some sort of adapter between the db object (how it is stored) and the object as an entity in code (how it is used).

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [Traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php)?

If it were up to me, I'd create a folder `App/Traits` and have for example a `UserActions` trait, that has the `getAllUncompletedActionsForUser()` function.

The trait `UserActions` can be used in any appropriate class/model.

Comment: If traits are the answer, then you are asking the wrong question.

Comment: @tereško Having seen your answer, yours is much more of a suitable solution. +1 Didn't know about data mappers.

Comment: There are also other patterns, like [table gateways](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableDataGateway.html) and some other options. You probably should try finding [this book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Enterprise-Application-Architecture-Addison-Wesley-Signature/dp/0321127420) somewhere. The reason why may people dislike traits so much is, that they actually are engine level copy-paste. The php interpretator physically copies in the code fragment, before it gets parsed.